# Jquery-Select2 Passing selected value to another select2

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have used select2 multiple (screenshot below)
https://prnt.sc/p8z18g

I have selected 2 options and in-text input, there are my values and options

I want to when I click on edit, it shows my selected values in my `edit-select2`  
https://prnt.sc/p8z1y9

Any idea how to do it?

In Add Operation (with bootstrap modal):

```php
<td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Item Remarks (Optional)</label>
            <?php
            $options = array();
            foreach ($itemremarks as $rows) {
                $options[$rows->pledge_item_remark] = $rows->pledge_item_remark;
            }
            $select = array(
                'style' => 'width:370px;',
                'name' => 'pledge_item_remark',
                'id' => 'pledge_item_remark',
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'multiple' => 'multiple'
            );
            echo form_dropdown('pledge_item_remark', $options, ($this->uri->segment(9) && $this->uri->segment(9) != 'NIL') ? $this->uri->segment(9) : set_value('pledge_item_remark'), $select);
            ?>
            <textarea type="text" name="child_item_remarks[]" id="child_item_remarks" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Remarks"></textarea>
        </td>
</td>
```

In Edit Operation (Bootstrap Modal)

```php
<td>
    <label>Item Remarks (Optional)</label>
    <?php
    $options = array();
    foreach ($itemremarks as $rows) {
        $options[$rows->pledge_item_remark] = $rows->pledge_item_remark;
    }
    $select = array(
        'style' => 'width:370px;',
        'name' => 'edit_place_child_item_remarks',
        'id'    => 'edit_place_child_item_remarks',
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'multiple' => 'multiple'
    );
    echo form_dropdown('edit_place_child_item_remarks', $options, ($this->uri->segment(9) && $this->uri->segment(9) != 'NIL') ? $this->uri->segment(9) : set_value('edit_place_child_item_remarks'), $select);
    ?>
    <textarea type="text" name="edit_place_child_item_remarks_text[]" id="edit_place_child_item_remarks_text" class="form-control" placeholder="Item Remarks"></textarea>
</td>
```